# Linking with ffmpeg shared build

Tags: dll, linker, ffmpeg, cygwin, shared-libraries

I am trying to work with the `ffmpeg` library on a `cygwin` development environment. I downloaded the [shared build from here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (64-bit). The `bin` folders contain `dlls` but no `.a` or `.dll.a` files. Linking, which is done like so:

```
$ gcc encoding_mp3.o -L/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/lib/w32api -L/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_shared/bin -lavcodec-54 -lm -luser32 -lpthread -o encoding_mp3
```

results in the following error:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_shared/bin/avcodec-54.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My question(s):
1. The `bin/` folder in the shared build contains only `avcodec-54.dll`. Is there a way to convert the `dll` to a `dll.a` or `.a`?
2. Where am I going wrong?

If source code is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the "dev" versions, or the "static linking" ones (a little down, on the page).
dlls cannot be converted to libs, nor can they be used (usually) to generate they own little import stubs (the .dll.a)

From the page you linked "Dev packages provide the headers and .lib/.dll.a files required to use the .dll files in other programs."
.a / .lib usually are located in "lib" folders.

Comment: Mingw gcc is able to link against dlls without the import libraries. (I'm unsure on cygwin gcc which the OP likely uses)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko didn't know that.. good to know! Does it walk the "IMPORT" section and generate stubs on the fly?

Comment: It walks the *exports* of dlls which are given as command line arguments, and yes, it's able to generate stubs on the fly when it has to.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko oh yes sorry, I meant export :) I suppose it only works when exporting by name, not by ordinal. But I have never found anyone exporting by ordinal, so...

Comment: Anyway, in the case of the OP, it should be much easier to download the correct package and use the .a from there. But it is good to know that mingw has this option. And i suspect that, as you said, the cygwin GCC will not work the same way; it uses a different convention for exporting symbols, IIRC

Comment: @dema80: I see `.dll.a` and `.lib` files in the lib/ folder of the dev package. Do I link against the .dll.a or the .lib file? What is the difference?

Comment: @Sriram depends on the library.. surely there is a readme or something like that in the package? Usually, .dll.a is the name given to the little stub that just provides the symbols to link to the dll, and the .lib contains the full static library (for static linking). But this varies vastly (in the MS world, for example, it is common to call .lib both files; you can tell them apart by their size)